# Natural Gas Modelling

Tags: finance, trading, models, commodities

In job adverts for natural gas/power trading it states knowledge of supply and demands models for these commodities. Does anyone know of any good papers or primers on S&D modelling?

Comment: The second hit when you Google this is a paper by the eia reviewing numerous different models. Is your question really "which of the models available do you guys think is best, from experience?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check papers wrote by Helyette Geman, or by Deng. I found Deng's research on stochastic models in energy really helpful